# query selecting dates at midnight day after specified range

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime

I have table `dates` with column `date` which is of `DATETIME` datatype. I have a php query which has the variable `period`, which is the interval for the upper limit of the range. the lower limit is always `NOW()`. The issue is when the interval is equal to one it also selects dates at midnight on the next day. One second passed midnight it does not select but

`tommorows date 00:00:00`  for some reason is also selected.

here is an example.

```
$period = 1;

$db->query(
           SELECT * FROM dates 
           WHERE date 
           BETWEEN NOW() AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL $period DAYS
          );
```

today, December 4th, this would select dates up to and including `2013-12-05 00:00:00`. Any ideas why this is happening as I can't find any reason why it is. Thank you for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between is INCLUSIVE, meaning the lower and upper limits are also included in the results. Try doing it with `>= lower limit` and `< upper limit`:

```sql
SELECT * FROM dates 
WHERE date >= NOW() AND date < CURDATE() + INTERVAL $period DAYS
```

Comment: Great. I'm glad I know this now. That has been very helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

That's because:

```
foo BETWEEN bar AND baz
```

is the equivalent of

```
(bar <= foo) AND (foo <= baz)
```

it's an inclusive comparison. Since you're doing dates, you end up with

```
('2013-12-04' <= `date`) AND (`date` <= '2013-12-05 00:00:00')
```

If you don't want the upper range to be inclusive, you'll have to use the long hand:

```
(bar <= foo) AND (foo < baz)
                      ^--- note
```